# ASP.NET Core FromBody is null on AJAX POST but populates in Postman

Tags: ajax, .net-core, postman

I'm trying to perform an AJAX post but I keep getting a null FromBody in my .NET controller. I think it has to do with how I'm formatting my AJAX post.

When I attempt to post with AJAX I get a null FromBody.

```
    var data = {
    Date: "2016-12-01",
    BurnIdx: 23,
    BurnStatIdx1: 3,
    BurnStatIdx2: 3,
    BurnStatIdx3: 3,
    BurnSevIdx: 5,
    WorkOrder: 32426,
    Comment: "Hi"
};

$('#submit').on('click',function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Home/BurnerMapUpdate',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('Data received');
            console.log(result);
        }

    });
});
```

[image: Null FromBody]

However, when I attempt a post in Postman it's successful.

[image: Postman]
[image: Not null]

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Ima
ges and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured out my problem. Needed to use JSON.stringify on my data.

```
    $('#submit').on('click',function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Home/BurnerMapUpdate',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('Data received');
            console.log(result);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not only the JSON.stringify().
If your data don't match with csharp class data it doesn't receive anything.
Like if you define in the class a field with int type, and send it in the json like "1", it happens to receive the whole data as null

Answer (score 0):

I know you are already figured out of this problem. But I faced with the same just right now. My mistake was I used **`BODY`** parameter instead **`DATA`** in ajax request.

My Invalid ajax:

```
function sendRequest(url, method, body, callbackOk, callbackFail) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        method: method,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: callbackOk,
        error: callbackFail
    })
```

Valid:

```
function sendRequest(url, method, body, callbackOk, callbackFail) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(body),
        method: method,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: callbackOk,
        error: callbackFail
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly I had the reverse problem: Almost exactly the same example that you provided but I was getting null passed to the controller. My fix was to remove JSON.stringify and it then worked.
It appears if you include contentType: 'application/json' then you have to use JSON.stringify on the data but if you don't include that then you must NOT stringify it